# What's the meaning of min/max=1 in AWS auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I am studying AWS, per the illustration in [AWS here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html):

[image]

For a min/max=1 case, what does it implicit to? Seems no scaling to me as min = max

Thank you for your kind enlightening.

UPDATE:

so here is an example use case:
http://www.briefmenow.org/amazon/how-can-you-implement-the-order-fulfillment-process-while-making-sure-that-the-emails-are-delivered-reliably/

> Your startup wants to implement an order fulfillment process for
>   selling a personalized gadget that needs an average of 3-4 days to
>   produce with some orders taking up to 6 months you expect 10 orders
>   per day on your first day. 1000 orders per day after 6 months and
>   10,000 orders after 12 months. Orders coming in are checked for
>   consistency men dispatched to your manufacturing plant for production
>   quality control packaging shipment and payment processing If the
>   product does not meet the quality standards at any stage of the
>   process employees may force the process to repeat a step Customers are
>   notified via email about order status and any critical issues with
>   their orders such as payment failure. Your case architecture includes
>   AWS Elastic Beanstalk for your website with an RDS MySQL instance for
>   customer data and orders. How can you implement the order fulfillment
>   process while making sure that the emails are delivered reliably?

Options:

```
A.
Add a business process management application to your Elastic Beanstalk app servers and re-use the ROS
database for tracking order status use one of the Elastic Beanstalk instances to send emails to customers.

B.
Use SWF with an Auto Scaling group of activity workers and a decider instance in another Auto Scaling group
with min/max=1 Use the decider instance to send emails to customers.

C.
Use SWF with an Auto Scaling group of activity workers and a decider instance in another Auto Scaling group
with min/max=1 use SES to send emails to customers.

D.
Use an SQS queue to manage all process tasks Use an Auto Scaling group of EC2 Instances that poll the tasks
and execute them. Use SES to send emails to customers.
```

The voted answer is C.

Can anyone kindly share the understanding? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, there will be no scaling outward or inward when min/max=1. Or when min=max. This situation is generally used for keeping a service available in case of failures.

Consider the alternative; you launch with an EC2 instance that's been bootstrapped with some user data script. If the instance has issues, you'll need to stop it and begin another.

Instead, you launch using an AutoScaling Group with a Launch Configuration that takes care of bootstrapping instances. If your application server begins to fail, you can just de-register it from the AutoScaling Group. AWS will take care of bringing up another instance while you triage the defective one.

Another situation you might consider is when you want the option to deploy a new version of an application with the same AutoScaling Group. In this case, create a new Launch Configuration and register it with the ASG. Increase max and desired by 1 temporarily. AWS will launch the instance for you and if it succeeds, you can then reduce Max and Desired back down to 1. By default, AWS will remove the oldest server but you can guarantee that the new one stays up by using termination protection.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Would really appreciate if you can comment on the new update to the original question.